# .NET Core 3.0 Console Application Cannot Read a File, throws UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-core

I created a .NET Core 3.0 MS Tests project (type Console Application).  I have a unit test that tries to read a file:

```
var imageFile = new System.IO.FileStream("../../../InputFiles/Documents/boksit.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Open);
```

When I run this, I get this error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '...boksit.pdf' is denied.
```

I am running on Windows 10 latest.  I have given the group Everyone access to this file and its containing folders.  I also tried to read a file from C:\temp\boksit.pdf and got the same result.

This is NOT an ASP.NET Application.  So why can't it simply read this file?  This is a unit test project, so need to be able to read files.  Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.  I am new to .NET Core, so apologies if this is basic - but I cannot find any answers for this issue; everything is for ASP.NET Core (which of course has a very different permissions model).

Comment: You should not read and write files in unit tests. If it fails for one reason or another other than buggy code then your test will fail for external reasons (which is what you are experiencing). What you wrote is an integration test, not a unit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.  The file had Read Only set in Windows.  This was set by my Version Control System (TFS).  Unchecking this fixed the issue.